# Need help opening my bitcoins that was save to my computer

Tags: wallet

About 5 or so years I received some bitcoins, they were kept in a bitcoin wallet, well the wallet became unresponsive so I backed the wallet onto my computer, but now I have no knowledge of how to open them and put them in another will download now. Does anyone know how this is done thanks?

Comment: Which wallet software were you using? What sort of backup do you have saved?

Comment: What is the filename of the backup? This can help in identifying the software needed to restore the wallet.